# docking window functionality in QML not working

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

I got inspired by this code https://github.com/wbt729/quickdock and extending it to make it work like native windows docking functionality like in Visual studio , where the user can grab the title bar and drag the window to mouse cursor.

I can drag and undock the window fine but it does not drag it to mouse cursor  when initially moved

here is the example of the code :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 
import QtQuick.Window 
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Item {
    id: root
    default property alias contents: placeholder.data
    property alias title: titleLabel.text
    implicitHeight: mainWindow.height - statusBar.height - 15
    
    Rectangle {
        
        id: content
        anchors.fill: parent       
        height: implicitHeight
        state: "docked"        
        border.color: "slategrey"
        border.width: 1
        ToolBar {         
            id: toolBar
            implicitHeight: 30
            Material.foreground: "white"
            Material.background: "#dcdcdc"            
            anchors { top: parent.top; left: parent.left; right: parent.right }            
            Label {
                id: titleLabel
                color: "black"
                anchors { left: parent.left; leftMargin: 8; verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter }
            }
            
            MouseArea {
                id: dragMouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
                property variant clickPos: "0,0"
                onPressed: (mouse) => {
                               clickPos = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)
                               if (content.state === "docked") {
                                   // Set the initial position of the window when undocked
                                   window.x = mouse.x
                                   window.y = mouse.y                        
                               }
                           }    
                
                onPositionChanged:  (mouse) => {
                                        var delta = Qt.point(mouse.x-clickPos.x, mouse.y-clickPos.y)
                                        var new_x = window.x + delta.x
                                        var new_y = window.y + delta.y
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        if (content.state === "docked") {
                                            // Check if the mouse is outside the bounds of the docked area
                                            if (mouse.y < toolBar.height || mouse.x < 0 || mouse.x > parent.width) {
                                                content.state = "undocked"
                                                // Move the window to the mouse position
                                                window.x = new_x
                                                window.y = new_y
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            // Get the maximum x and y positions for the undocked window
                                            var max_x = Screen.desktopAvailableWidth - window.width
                                            var max_y = Screen.desktopAvailableHeight - window.height
                                            
                                            // Update the window position, making sure it stays within the screen bounds
                                            if (new_x < 0) new_x = 0
                                            if (new_x > max_x) new_x = max_x
                                            if (new_y < 0) new_y = 0
                                            if (new_y > max_y) new_y = max_y
                                            
                                            window.x = new_x
                                            window.y = new_y
                                            
                                            
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                
                onClicked: {
                    if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton)
                        contextMenu.popup()
                }
                
                Menu {
                    id: contextMenu
                    MenuItem { id: dockMenu; text: "Dock"; onClicked: content.state = "docked"; implicitHeight: 30}
                    MenuItem { id: unDockMenu; text: "Float"; onClicked: content.state = "undocked" ; implicitHeight: 30}  
                }
            }           
            
        }
        Item {
            id: placeholder
            anchors { top: toolBar.bottom; left: parent.left; right: parent.right; bottom: parent.bottom }
        }
        states: [
            State {
                name: "undocked"
                PropertyChanges { target: root; height: 0 }
                PropertyChanges { target: window; visible: true }
                ParentChange { target: content; parent: undockedContainer }
                //PropertyChanges { target: window; visible: true; x: 250; y: 250 }
                //this is to make sure the width becomes zero and rest of the control takes the realstate
                PropertyChanges {target: navigationWindow; width: 0 }
                PropertyChanges {target: toolBar; Material.background: "#f0e68c" }
                PropertyChanges {target: unDockMenu; enabled: false }
                PropertyChanges {target: dockMenu; enabled: true } 
            },
            State {
                name: "docked"
                PropertyChanges { target: root; height: implicitHeight }
                PropertyChanges { target: window; visible: false }
                ParentChange { target: content; parent: root }
                PropertyChanges {target: unDockMenu; enabled: true }
                PropertyChanges {target: dockMenu; enabled: false } 
            }
        ]
    }
    Window {
        id: window
        width: 250;
        height: 700;
        
        flags: Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
        
        Item {         
            id: undockedContainer
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        
        onClosing: {
            content.state = "docked"
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one aproach to solve your positioning problem. Remove the onPress function and change the onPositionChanged function to this:

```
property point relativePos;

onPositionChanged:  (mouse) => {
     // get the mouse pos in screen coordinates
     let globalMousePos = mapToGlobal(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y));
     var new_x = globalMousePos.x;
     var new_y = globalMousePos.y;

     if (content.state === "docked") {
        // Check if the mouse is outside the bounds of the docked area
       if (mouse.y < toolBar.height || mouse.x < 0 || mouse.x > parent.width) {
           console.log("Initial window position: " + new_x + " " + new_y);
           content.state = "undocked"
           //  store the click point where the drag started
           relativePos = mapToItem(root, Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y));
           window.x = new_x - relativePos.x;
           window.y = new_y - relativePos.y;
        }
    } else {
         console.log("Move the window to the mouse position: " + new_x + " " + new_y);
         window.x = Math.max(0,
                    Math.min(new_x - relativePos.x, Screen.desktopAvailableWidth - window.width));
         window.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(new_y - relativePos.y, Screen.desktopAvailableHeight - window.height));
     }

 }
```

See the comments for more details.

Comment: Lutz -appreciate your response, however it does seem to work. Please note my problem is when i first undock it and move by dragging it , it should be positioned where the mouse position is but it is still not working . once i release the mouse and position the window it works (onPositionchanged). 

So , i believe onPress needs to be there and somehow onPositionChanged should know where it started from.

Comment: When I run my code, the drag starts at the mouse position. But there is a problem in dragging at first. Don't know why the window is moving with the wrong delta. But the start position of the drag is correct. It is also correct if you start the drag, release the mouse and then start dragging again. But this is another problem and not the drag start thing. Just try it with a small movement of the mouse to check the window start positioning.

Comment: yeah, you are correct, the initial position is correct but the window is moving with wrong delta and that is what i was seeing in my original solution as well.

Comment: do you have any ideas to how to correct it? I am just running out of idea?